# How do I get_the_content in a custom walker?

Tags: walker

I have a custom walker and I would like to either `get_the_content()` (up to the Read More) or `get_the_excerpt()` to use in this walker, but I can't figure out how to get it to work - it either returns nothing, or if I put an `$item->object_id` in it (thinking maybe it needed the post/page ID), then it just returns that ID and not the actual post/page text.

I tried googling

Here is my code:

```
class Salamander_AdventMore_Walker extends Walker_page {
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    if ( $depth ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    } else {
        $indent = '';
    }

    $advent_slug = get_post_meta($item->object_id, 'advent-slug', true);
    $advent_small_title = get_post_meta($item->object_id, 'advent-title', true);
    $advent_title = ( !empty($advent_small_title) ? $advent_small_title : $advent_slug);

    $advent_content = apply_filters('the_content', $item->object_id);
    $advent_content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $advent_content);

    // this doesn't work
    // $advent_content = get_the_content( $item->object_id, 'Read more ...' ) ;

    $output .= $indent . '
    <li>
      <section>
        <h1>' . $advent_title . '</h1>
        <div id="day'. $advent_slug .'" class="daydetail-content">
          <div class="right">
            <hgroup>
              <h2>' . $advent_title . '</h2>
            </hgroup>
            '. $advent_content .'
          </div><!-- ends right -->
          <div class="left">
            <!--<a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.oia.co.za/wp-content/uploads/currency_by_abcdz2000_Flickr-356x703.jpg" width="356" alt=""/></a>-->
          </div><!-- ends left -->
        </div><!-- ends daydatail-content -->
      </section>
    ';
} // ends function
} // ends class
```

Comment: Alternatively, I'd be happy with how to do a regular query, but with the selection of posts from a particular menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who might be looking for the same thing, this is what I did in the end:

I abandoned the Custom Walker idea and used `wp_get_nav_menu_items` to get a list of post IDs from my custom menu, from this tutorial on **Digging into WordPress**: http://digwp.com/2011/11/html-formatting-custom-menus/

In my functions file, I created this function:

```
function salamander_fetch_advent_posts() {
 global $post_list;
 $menu_name = 'advent-calendar'; // specify custom menu slug
 if ( ($locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[$menu_name] ) ) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[$menu_name]);
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

    $post_list = array();
    foreach ((array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item) {
        $post_id = $menu_item->object_id;
        $post_list[] = $post_id;
    }
  }
  return $post_list ;
}
```

And then in my theme template file, I passed `$post_list` to a new query, like so:

```
global $post_list;
if (function_exists( salamander_fetch_advent_posts() )) {
    salamander_fetch_advent_posts();
}

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post__in' => $post_list,
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) ) ;

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```